# How to get the record in MySQL using the path location?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and it have 5 Million record.
It create the performance impact.
Please suggest for performance tunning.

```
SELECT 
    Path,
    Id,
    Endtime
FROM 
    Backup
WHERE 
    Source_Path 
LIKE 
    '%/Fold1/Fold2/Fold3/Fold4/Fold4%' 
AND
    status='SUCCESS';
```

Comment: remove first wildcard character and prefix with common rootpath ... `WHERE 
    Source_Path 
LIKE 
    'rootPath/Fold1/Fold2/Fold3/Fold4/Fold4%' ` .. this helps in use of indexes

Comment: @mhasan - It is in middle of Source Path. So i cant give the exact path it will be generate n the running time.

Comment: First, I had to Google _lakhs_ to know what it was (I knew it was an Indian unit of quantity, but didn't recall how much). I would be best if you adhere to international concepts and wording. Second, you are examining 5 million strings searching for your  value. Third, you may try splitting your query into two (assuming that the percent of "SUCCESS" is high) such that you first remove records with `status <> 'SUCCESS'` and then you only check strings for the relevant potential records. In this way, the inner query returns the reduced set and the outer the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have what I wrote as a comment:

```
SELECT Path   ,  Id   , Endtime
  FROM ( SELECT Path , Id , Endtime , Source_Path 
           FROM Backup
          WHERE status='SUCCESS'
        )
 WHERE Source_Path LIKE '%/Fold1/Fold2/Fold3/Fold4/Fold4%' ;
```

Note: If, say, 99% of your records have 'SUCCESS', then this approach will not show any significant improvement (since you would still need to examine 5 million strings).

Comment: Yes correct. Faced the same issue. Do you have any other idea.

Comment: I'm sorry, but will not put any additional effort on this unless you explain me why my proposed solution is not good for you.

Comment: We need to show the table of records in which the status = success and the path contains "%/Fold1/Fold2/Fold3/Fold4/Fold5%" (name changed). as of now table have 5 million records.

Comment: Did you try what I posted?

Comment: I tried but still it is taking time to purge the data.

Comment: Please post what percentage of your records include 'SUCCESS' and how much time the process takes.

Comment: Have 98% of records are success and it took 10 mins for 0.1 million data

Comment: So, you have 100,000 string comparisons... 10 mins is indeed too much. I'd suggest you check the server's resources while the query runs.